# Show that there exists constant $C$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,x_n\rangle |^2\le C \|f\|^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be Hilbert space.

I have to show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,x_n\rangle|^2 < \infty, \:\:\: f\in H$

then there exists constant $C\ge 0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,x_n\rangle|^2\le C \|f\|^2, \:\:\: f\in H$

Is this somehow connected with Bessel inequality? Could you give my any tips?

Comment: Finite for all $f$ or for some $f$? I guess for all $f$...

Comment: Obviously for all $f$

Comment: You want to use the open mapping theorem, or closed graph theorem, in some manner.

Comment: Yes otherwise it's trivial =P

Comment: Would Riesz representation theorem be useful here?

Comment: What are the $x_n$? Some Hilbert basis? Some family of pairwise orthogonal vectors?

Comment: $(x_n)$ is just an arbitrary sequence of vectors from $H$. Not necessarily orthogonal.

Comment: This $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,x_n\rangle|^2 < \infty$ holds for any $f$ and $(x_n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, it holds .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis in $H$. Define an operator $A:H\to H$ by
$$
 Af=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle f,x_n\rangle e_n
$$
and apply the Banach-Steinhaus theorem to prove that $A$ is bounded. Indeed, set
$$
A_mf=\sum_{n=1}^m\langle f,x_n\rangle e_n.
$$
Then $A_mf\to Af$ for every $f\in H$ and hence $A_m$ are uniformly bounded by Banach-Steinhaus and $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Could you explain me why you are constructing such an operator and how do we know it is bounded (in order to apply banach-steinhaus)?

Comment: Because $||Af||^2$ is just the sum of squares you need to estimate in terms of $||f||^2$, so your problem is reworded as "prove that $A$ is bounded". And for this sort of task, there are various theorems. In your case, Banach-Steinhaus applies.

Comment: COuld you also explain how $||Af||^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,x_n\rangle|^2$ ? EDIT: sorry I know, $e_n$ are orthonormal. everything is okay

Comment: See the edited answer where I added how to use B-S

Comment: Sorry again, where we use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,x_n\rangle|^2 < \infty, \:\:\: f\in H$?

Comment: Exactly where we 1) see that $Af$ is well defined (the series converges); 2) see that $A_mf\to Af$ (again because the series converges).

Comment: And we only use the fact that $|\langle f,x_n\rangle| \rightarrow 0$

Comment: I just can;t see how we can conclude that $Af=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle f,x_n\rangle e_n < \infty$ from $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,x_n\rangle|^2 < \infty$. Could you explain? It is my last question. I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Since the vectors $e_n$ are orthonormal, we can use Pythagoras' formula to compute the norm of the sum: $||\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2}\langle f,x_n\rangle e_n||^2=\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2}|\langle f,x_n\rangle|^2$.